# Display the name of the day 2 days ahead of current day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

currently I'm doing a calender/scheduler. How do i display the name of the day that is 2 days ahead of the current day.(eg. today is wednesday so i'm suppose to display friday) Currently what i did was this.

```
var d=new Date();
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

Comment: `new Date.today().addDays(2)`

Comment: I've added a [fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21424510/1636522) for [ling.s's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21423775/1636522) since I feel it's a cleaner one.

Comment: See the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/346L8/2/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following sample `+d` gives the same result as `d.getTime()` :

```
// 3600000ms (=1h) x 48 = 2 days
var n = weekday[new Date(+d + 3600000 * 48).getDay()]
```

I also really like [ling.s's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21423775/1636522), but it needs a little fix :

```
// friday.getDay() -> 5
// weekday[5 + 2] -> undefined
// weekday[(5 + 2) % 7] -> "Sunday"
var n = weekday[(d.getDay() + 2) % 7];
```

Here is one way to display it :

```
<span id="twoDaysLater"></span>
```

```js
var weekday = [
    'Sunday',
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday'
];

var now = new Date();
var twoDaysLater = new Date(+now + 3600000 * 48);
var dayName = weekday[twoDaysLater.getDay()];

jQuery(function ($) {
    // DOM is now ready
    $('#twoDaysLater').text(dayName);
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/346L8/.

Based on [ling.s's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21423775/1636522) : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/346L8/2/.

Answer (score 2):

Demo [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/k7bU8/)

**Jquery**

```
    var d=new Date();
 d.setDate(d.getDate()+2);
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

alert(weekday[d.getDay()]);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! how do i display that date using javascript in my table. I tried document.write but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add +2 because `getDay()` returns the day.

```
var n = weekday[d.getDay()+2];
```

Here is the example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHTcL/)

Comment: above code is not correct what about current date is on friday or saturday